# Где лучше(безопаснее) всего в программе хранить пароль от БД?

Tags: c++, qt, безопасность, взлом

Есть программа, которая взаимодействует в ходе работы с БД. Само собой БД с паролем. Обычно разные служебные данные и конфиги выносят в отдельный файл `.conf`, так делаю и я. Но пароль, насколько я понимаю, там хранить небезопасно, ведь `.conf` сможет любой открыть пользователь и прочитать адрес и пароль БД и пиши пропало. Какое для этого есть решение?

PS: хардкодить не вариант:

1. не практично, вдруг пароль поменяется
2. многие ЯП (C++ например) после компиляции хранят строки в `exe` файле в неизменном виде (можете проверить в hello_world.exe поиском найти строку hello world :) )

Мои инструменты:
C++ и Qt, PostgreSQL,
БД на сервере, то есть клиентское ПО отправляет SQL запросы, они на сервере исполняются в СУБД и возвращается ответ

Решение желательно без дополнительных серверов.

Comment: важный пароль к базе данных зашифровать простой прогой типа XOR заменой простым паролем программы *(вас как юзера)*. При запуске проги запускаете её и она XOR-ит вашим простым паролем пароль базы данных и получаете реально расшифрованный пароль. Надёжность зависит от длины и сложности ваших паролей.

Comment: Скорее всего пользователь вообще не должен иметь прямого доступа к бд. Если ваше приложение ходит в бд и при этом выполняется в недоверенной среде (у пользователя) — значит, вероятно, вы делаете что-то очень сильно не так

Comment: @andreymal я не совсем понял ваш ответ, вы бы не могли разъяснить подробнее, что я делаю не так? И вероятно, вы можете посоветовать литературу, где я могу об этом почитать/научиться этому?

Comment: .conf-файл просто не надо разрешать читать каким попало пользователям. Режим 0600 — и до свидания.

Comment: @user_587 Вы видимо не в курсе, как работают подобные файловые разрешения. *"режим 0600"* фактически устанавливает только номинальные ограничения

Comment: @user7860670 угу, вы правы, я не в курсе.

Comment: Какая СУБД? Какая ОС? / Как тут некоторые уже сказали, если посторонний получил доступ к учётке, он всегда сможет достать зашифрованный пароль, потому что код его расшифровки присутствует в программе. / Достаточно использовать способ наподобие `Trusted Connection = true` для Sql Server - это означает, что используется аутентификация ОС.

Comment: Тут в комментах ниже напрашивается уточняющий вопрос — где расположена база? Локальная (таскается вместе с приложением целиком) или где-то на удалённом сервере?

Comment: Ну и ещё как минимум одному человеку в комментах ниже не очевидно — в какой среде запускается приложение, подконтрольной вам или нет? Вы являетесь администратором компьютера, на котором устанавливается/запускается приложение, или вы просто отдаёте exe-файл клиенту и дальше он сам разбирается? Являются ли пользователи этого приложения непривилегированными, или они могут иметь полный доступ к компьютеру, на котором запускается приложение?

Comment: О, вижу проблески мыслей. По поводу компьютерной безопасности: читайте https://infobez.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/10-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/, например, и всё остальное, что можно найти в Интернете. Даже если не брать в расчёт безопасность, то ни в какой коммерческой системе нельзя давать пользователю права администратора.

Comment: @rotabor вы всё ещё оторваны от реальной жизни. Реальные владельцы реальных коммерческих систем хранят все пароли в гугл-таблице (хорошо если додумаются ограничить к ней доступ) и пересылают ЭЦП вместе с незапароленным закрытым ключом через почту mail.ru (и я не шучу). Ну а запароленный компьютер это вообще вопиюще недопустимо, потому что НИУДОБНА

Comment: бд+redis
так как в программе не то что не стоит, а вообще не нужно, любой пользователь сможет получить доступ к данным

Comment: @andreymal
Будем считать что субд хранится и работает отдельным сервисом на сервере. root права у пользователя есть. Я не контролирую среду клиента

Comment: @user_587
Режим 0600 это формально, у пользвотеля есть root права

Comment: @Alexander Petrov oc linux

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Вы слишком доверяете клиенту, и тогда смысла в шифровании и безопасности никакого. Или Вы не доверяете, тогда все данные сохраняются, отправляются и обрабатываются через бэкенд через веб-сервер. Прямого доступа к БД быть в таком случае не должно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никакого способа защищенно хранить пароли в программе нет. Пользователю доступны все ее данные, включая пароль и содержимое из базы данных. Максимум, чего вы сможете добиться - обфускации пароля.
Для защищенного хранения паролей и т.п. чувствительных данных необходимо использование аппаратного носителя с неизвлекаемыми ключами.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139993/discussion-on-answer-by-user7860670--------).

Answer (score 4):

Если бд на сервере, то сервер должен выполнять с ней работу => все логины и пароли должны храниться на сервере. Программа же должна общаться с сервером посредством запросов, в которых передаются данные, с которыми мы хотим что-то сделать

Comment: А для авторизации работы с этой программой на сервере (прокси) все равно понадобится локально хранимый пароль. Но это не пароль базы, поэтому с базой в любом случае можно будет делать только то, что реализовано в прокси

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 варианта:

1. Вынести пароль и ссылку к бд в dll который при необходимости будет обновляться.
2. Создать файл, с определенным методом шифрования и дешифрования (тут есть разные варианты реализации), а ключ к дешифровки хранить непосредственно в .exe файле.

Но лично я бы написал бы простой PHP скрипт на сервере, который бы обращался к базе данных. Если говорить про обычный хостинг, и у пользователя уже хранить в .exe статичную ссылку, а на сервере уже хранить пароль.

Comment: любые строки, которые мы храним в скомпилированных файлах читаются, если этот файл открыть как txt

Comment: @SpaceResearcher тогда шифровать строку в с++ и сохраняй ее хэш, а после запуска программы, считывай хэш из файла и декодируй

Comment: пароль поменяется - менять хеш в проге  - перекомпиливать, к тому же этот хеш нереально расшифровать же :) Должно быть какое-то хорошее решение,  но я его пока не нашел

Comment: @SpaceResearcher сделай тогда по третьему варианту **Но лично я бы написал бы простой php скрипт на сервере, который бы обращался к базе данной, если говорить про обычный хостинг, и у пользователя уже хранить в .exe статичную ссылку, а на сервере уже хранить пароль.**

Comment: *"ключ к дешифровки хранить непосредственно в .exe файле"* - это эквивалентно хранению пароля базы в .exe c небольшой обфускацией

Answer (score 0):

Мой ответ подразумевает, что речь идёт о локальной системе, т. е. клиентское приложение запускается на том же компьютере, где находится и СУБД, и БД.

Пароль нужно хранить в .conf в зашифрованном виде. Программа читает конфигурацию и дешифрует пароль, используя ключ, жёстко забитый в код программы.

Аргументы: 1) пароль не должен быть зашит в коде, чтобы его можно было менять; 2) пароль не должен быть доступен в открытом виде в конфигурационном файле.

Другого варианта нет. И этот вариант, как и любой другой, не защищён от реверс-инжиниринга.

Если это секретный пароль, то обновлять его в конфигурационном файле нужно с помощью другой программы, в которую забит тот же ключ шифрования.

Тут предлагают всякие варианты с хостингом, серверами и пр. интернетом, но в условии о доступе в сеть речи нет. Это может быть локальная база данных, которую нужно защитить от несанкционированного доступа пользователя. Это сразу отсекает метод защиты через аутентификацию средствами ОС. Защита БД осуществляется приложением, так как только приложение может менять БД и только запрограммированным образом, исключая риск намеренного или ненамеренного повреждения или изменения данных.

Появилась мысль, сам делал такое недавно. Исходя из гипотезы локального применения. Нужно защитить приложение от доступа. Сделать его в виде службы с Web-интерфейсом, приложение запускается от какой-то выделенной учётной записи, доступ к файлам и папкам приложения только у этой учётной записи (ну и система, и администраторы, понятно). Таким образом, нельзя будет изучить исполняемый файл приложения, его бибилиотеки, конфигурационные и другие файлы.

Естественно, всё это подразумевает, что пользователь не обладает правами администратора и не может получить административный доступ к системе.

С **уточнёнными условиями** неободимо сделать следующее:

1. доступ к БД осуществляет серверное backend-ПО;
2. клиентское приложение подключается к серверу с помощью учётных данных, которые пользователь вводит интерактивно.

Таким образом, в приложении и его конфигурационных файлах никакие пароли не хранятся.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139994/discussion-on-answer-by-rotabor---------).

Comment: Ну вот, автор вопроса теперь явно написал, что у пользователя таки есть права администратора

Comment: А мог бы сразу написать, и про сетевую организацию тоже. Да, и в случае распределённой реализации вектор атаки меняется на man in the middle - и никакой защиты. Не вводите автора вопроса в заблуждение, что может быть какая-то защита. Для локальных систем в этом случае физически защищают сеть от доступа путём блокировки и отключения портов коммутаторов, отключения портов компьютеров, ну и последнее - в шкаф и на замок, снаружи только терминал.

Comment: Интересный факт: Chrome хранит пароли в зашифрованном виде, но с привязкой ключа шифрования к железу. Таким образом, если скопировать файл с паролями и открыть на другом компе - они не расшифруются

Comment: @andreymal а тут такое бывает, что вопрос бесследно исчезает вместе с ответом?

Answer (score 0):

Если нету посредника, который будет соединятся с базой - пароль в том или ином виде **не может не быть на клиенте**. Клиенту нужно использовать пароль чтоб установить соединение с БД.

Возможно, существуют движки БД или плагины для них, которые позволяют установить соединение с помощью аппаратных ключей или одноразовых токенов, но это довольно редкие варианты, и рассматривать их не буду.

Так же, под "БД" я представляю какую-то СУБД типа MySQL, где очень мало возможностей ограничения доступа.
Возможно, у вас другой движок БД, где сервер представляет всю нужную защиту данных и разграничение доступов, и ваша задача - именно спрятать пароль от соединения в обход клиентской программы.

Соответственно, ответ исходит из этой точки зрения.

---

Думаю, лучше всего хранить пароль - в зашифрованном виде в конфиге.

На счет шифрования - алгоритм должен быть проверенный временем, то есть например AES. Без велосипедов.

Ключ шифрования - частично захардкодить, частично вычислять в рантайме (например, операции над массивом). Так как компилятор может оптимизировать такой код, следует его написать так, чтоб компилятор не догадался, что результат будет константой.
Очень хорошее решение - так же использовать идентификаторы привязанные к железу. Например, "Volume Serial Number" раздела, на котором лежит программа. Тогда даже если скопировать программу на флешку - он не будет работать.

Ну и всю эту красоту прогнать через HMAC.

---

Еще один мелкий лайфхак обфускации: прогнать base64 через шифр цезаря =)

---

Еще один интересный способ хранения пароля, который я использовал в одном проекте (в описании я немного упростил схему):
Пароль зашифрован ключем, который есть хешем числа от 1 до 10000. Ни ключ ни это число не сохраняются нигде. При установлении соединения ключ шифрования пароля подбирается в реальном времени. Так же имеется хеш пароля, чтоб убедится что ключ расшифрован правильно.

Comment: Всё это не поможет абсолютно никак, потому что клиент прочитает готовый вычисленный ключ тупо из оперативной памяти

Comment: @andreymal разве? Пароль обычно используется только для соединения с базой. После того как соединение установлено и пароль больше не нужен - можно очистить память и освободить переменную

Comment: Ничто не помешает клиенту прочитать пароль ещё перед очисткой памяти

Comment: @andreymal это мгновение между расшифровкой пароля, отправкой и очисткой памяти? Ну можно еще насыпать мусора в памяти, чтоб было сложнее найти

Answer (score 0):

Не храните пароль в программе. Заставьте пользователя зарегистрироваться - создать свои логин и пароль. Дальше пользователь введя их получает временный одноразовый для подключения. OAuth, JWT используют чаще всего. Если программка рассчитана на узкий круг и не интересна в глобальном плане, то хотя бы сделайте отдельную учётку для пользователя только с нужными правами и пусть он сам хранит свой пароль.

Answer (score -2):

Сам пароль лучше не хранить нигде , только хеш , в крайнем случаее evn

Comment: вероятно, стоит расшифровать аббревиатуру evn (прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit])

Comment: наверное имелось ввиду env?